# Map file to URL

Tags: linux, files, http

I'm looking for a way to do something like this:

```
some_tool --go-to-background http://server.com/~me/uber_vimrc ~/.vimrc
```

After which, reading `~/.vimrc` would give the data downloaded from that URL. Read-only mapping is enough, though support for writing (through a REST API or whatever) would be cool. Is this possible with some existing utility?

**The key aspect I am after is mapping individual URL to individual file from user account on demand.** Needing a system daemon to support this is ok, and other schemes like *ftp* or *scp* would be ok too, does not have to be *http(s)*.

---

If there's no existing utility, what would be the general mechanism to implement this myself? Symbolic link to FUSE file system which implements the network communication part comes to mind as a possible way. Is there any simpler way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `avfs`:

```
mkdir ~/.avfs
avfsd ~/.avfs
ln -s ~/.avfs/'#http:server.com|~me|uber_vimrc' ~/.vimrc
```

For writing, you could use webdav. avfs supports a (great) number of network protocols and other methods to access files and adding more is relatively easy.

For mounting over sftp, look at sshfs.

Comment: Seems to work, great :). I was a bit surprised Fedora 19 didn't seem to have `avfs` package (or I didn't find one), but compiling it worked fine (after installing `fuse-devel`).